# Difference between TIFF image vs TIFF file

Tags: image, image-processing, tiff, image-compression

[image]

These 2 files are TIFF files but the file type is different, one is **TIFF IMAGE** and **TIFF File**. Can someone tell me the difference between them? I can't find the exact reason.

**EDIT:**

After enabling file extension

[image]

Comment: Turn on the option to show file extensions. On Windows it is the file extension that determines the file type. Maybe the file called “TIFF” has no extension, and thus Windows doesn’t know what to do with it, and tries to fill the type column using the file name? Either way, there is only one TIFF file standard, and it is the contents of the file that determine if it is a TIFF file or not, the extension is secondary.

Comment: So it looks like your Windows installation has a different description for files with a '.tif' extension and '.tiff' extension. These are both valid extensions according to the TIFF standard, they should not be distinguished like this. They likely are both TIFF files (though you can't tell for sure until you look inside).

Comment: I used a metadata extractor online to get the information about these files. It showed the 2nd image as JPEG, 1st image as TIFF.